# Binding Kendo DataGrid using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, datagrid, kendo-ui

I am passing information from the controller to a view like so:

```
return View(data);
```

How can I access this data within the View so to databind to a KendoDataGrid?
I have the following code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyCustomerModel>
<div id="StatementGrid"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var lines = [{ TransactionDate: "01/01/2014", TransactionNumber: "001" }];//this works
        var lines2 = @model //How to pass the model information here?

        var grid = $("#StatementGrid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
                { field: "TransactionDate", title: "Date" },
                { field: "TransactionNumber", title: "Transaction Number" }
            ],
            dataSource: {
                data:lines
                //data:lines2 //this does not work
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* Json encode your model and set your JavaScript lines variable equal to that value like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyCustomerModel>


<div id="StatementGrid"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var lines = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))

        var grid = $("#StatementGrid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
                { field: "TransactionDate", title: "Date" },
                { field: "TransactionNumber", title: "Transaction Number" }
            ],
            dataSource: {
                data:lines
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

You will have to set the date data type and format, but it will work. That being said, I definitely DO NOT recommend that approach AT ALL. Instead, I would look at the Telerik documentation on how to bind using remote or local data at the following links and follow their guidance:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/remote-data.html

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/local-data.html

Comment: Thank you Sean, this worked. As an aside could you elaborate on why this method is not an acceptable approach? Is it because it does not allow further paging / sorting / filtering on the grid?